# php utf-8 encoding for chinese text

Tags: php, utf-8

I am doing migration to generate SQL from one DB to another.

I am trying to get the output [image]

But when I did a `mb_convert_encoding("Mr.Wang (王老板)",  'UTF-8', 'Windows-1252')`

I have the output as [image]

I have those two extra "box". Any idea what am I doing wrong?

phpMyAdmin is able to export my old database containing chinese text in correct format, how do it do that in script?

*updated the images to better show my view

Comment: Why do you need to convert between encodings in the first place? What encoding is the data stored in in your database, what character encoding is the database connection using, etc. …?

Comment: hi, both my database is in utf8_general_ci. I am changing table name and fields because of my migration. 

I found out that by exporting(phpmyadmin) my first db using "'Mr.Wang (çŽ‹è€æ¿)" I will be able to display it correctly in my second db but I have problem if my output is the one with extra 2 blanks.

Comment: I am writing sql script as batch insert to bulk insert my new data.

Comment: You cannot encode Chinese characters in Windows-1252 to begin with. Your handling of encodings is completely screwed up somewhere!

Comment: All my previous database using those strange text is working. Perhaps my UTF8 migration need different function instead of encoding function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the header in the script to UTF8? What I normally use is the following:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

That has worked for me so far for German characters & some Arabic & Japanese etc.

Comment: Yes, i just added those but it has the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I actually need to

`mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");`

before my select statement. And I do not need to run  mb_convert_encoding("Mr.Wang (王老板)", 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1252') at all.

Now if I write my insert sql I got the correct text i wanted.